# Redirecting a bash error

Tags: bash, redirect

I am writing a bash script, which has a problem:

```
path=$(pwd)
data=$(ls -al $path) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

The problem occurs if `$path` is a "locked" directory (no permission for user x), call it "BadDir".  In that case, the program outputs:

```
ls: cannot access /home/user/.../BadDir/..: Permission denied
```

All I want is to hide this output.
I know there is redirection to `/dev/null` but I don't know how to use it in this particular case.

Comment: Just `data=$(ls -al $path 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: @fedorqui you should write this in an answer, so the question could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect all error message to another with using `EXEC`

for test, first create folder

```
mkdir /tmp/t/
sudo chown root /tmp/t/
sudo chgrp root /tmp/t/
sudo chmod 400 /tmp/t/
```

e.g:

```
ls -al /tmp/t/
```

output:

```
ls: cannot open directory /tmp/t/: Permission denied
```

and using `EXEC` first of file:

```
exec 2>/dev/null
ls -al /tmp/t/
```

with `exec` you can control and redirect all `error message` or another output